# Play a video from a memory stream in C#

Tags: c#, .net, video

Is it possible to play a video file which is stored in the memory stream ?

I need to develop a Windows Forms application. I tried to experiment with the Windows Media Player Control, DirectX SDK, but as far as I know all of them do not work with streams (in particular with the memory stream)

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Perhaps if you gave us some more details about what you are trying to do we could help more.

Comment: More details like platform (ASP.NET, Windows Forms, WPF, etc???)

Comment: I need to develop a Windows Forms application. I tried to experiment with the Windows Media Player Control, DirectX SDK, but as far as I know all of them doesn't work with the streams (in particular with the memory stream)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Play video file from a memory stream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890353/play-video-file-from-a-memory-stream)